# Find Cycles in Organic Graphs

Tags: c#, detection, cycle

I want to find all cycles in a graph that is built organically. In a nutshell cycles happen when two branches or paths end at a common vertex. Something like
1->2->3->4
1->5->4
form the cycle of 1->2->3->4->5->1.

Due to the nature of the graph I cannot use DFS or similar algorithms, because there are no back-edges. I have found [Find All Cycle Bases In a Graph, With the Vertex Coordinates Given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023310/find-all-cycle-bases-in-a-graph-with-the-vertex-coordinates-given) and [Algorithms to Identify All the Cycle Bases in a UnDirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607124/algorithms-to-identify-all-the-cycle-bases-in-a-undirected-graph) to go into the right direction, but no efficient algorithm was presented in the two threads.

Is there an optimized solution in either pseudocode or implemented form or should I lean towards any of the presented solutions and optimize it myself? In the latter case, which offered code sample should I use for this purpose?

Looking forward to your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DFS if right for you.

Explore the grapth till you  encounter vertex that was already explored

This is the pseudocode:

```
function DFSFindCycle(Start, Goal)
push(Stack,Start)
while Stack is not empty
    var Node := Pop(Stack)
    Color(Node, Grey)
    for Child in ExpandNotExploredEdges(Node)
        if Node.color != White
    return true 
        if Node.color = White
           push(Stack, Child)
           label edge e, Node:Child as explored
    Color(Node, Black)
retrun false
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I will try and report back if I am stuck again. Edit: I think I need to rework how input data is being prepared to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I got a DFS working with sample input, but whenever I use the generated graph as input it fails to find any cycles. Maybe you could help me in this regard, since I seem to be stuck in a logical blackhole.

Please note that input data is ordered like this:
vertex vert got zero or more root vertices.

I am looking at the following pseudocode:

```
nodes = dictionary(Vector2, Vertex)
vertices = GetData()

for each vertex in vertices

    bBackEdge = false
    //Check if vertex already exists
    //If true, we got a back-edge
    if nodes[vertex.Vector]
        tempVertex = nodes[vertex.Vector]
        bBackEdge = true
    else
        tempVertex = new Vertex(...)
        nodes.add(tempVertex.Vector, tempVertex )
    end of if

    for each root in tempVertex.Roots
        if nodes[root.Vector]
            tempRoot = nodes[root.Vector]
            tempRoot.Children.Add(vein)
            if bBackEdge
                vein.Children.Add(tempRoot)
            end of if
        end of if
    end of for
end of for
```

Comment: this code is very different form the one that I propose (you don't use color for vertex and use stack ). I think stick to my code ..

Comment: Yes it is. It is no DFS, but the algorithm I am using to find back-edges in the organic graph before feeding it to DFS. My apologies for the confusion. Since I got a basic cycle detection and enumeration working, I thought it would be wise to share it with you. 

Since you advise to use DFS, preparing input data correctly is really important to get the desired results. However that's where I am stuck now. So if you could take a look at the above pseudocode and give some feedback, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: first I don't see where you return bBackEdge. second for eahc vertex to change it back to false.I understand that this work for the simple cases , but I think me approach solve all the cases ....

Comment: I ticked your answer as accepted. Your original answer is helpful, because I know which algorithm to use. I will probably create a new thread about preparing data at some point, but first I will do something else and return to this issue later. Sometimes it helps to grow some distance between me and problems.