# How to find all the polygonal shapes of given the vertices?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry, planar-graph

I have a list of vertices and I know the connections between them. I am trying to find all the polygonal shapes of the vertices. These polygonal shapes should not overlap.

I did some research and I thought that I could detect the polygonal shapes, if I can traverse over the vertices on clockwise, (or counter-clockwise, doesn’t make a difference).
So, I search for solutions to traverse over the vertices on clockwise. And I found a [similar topic](/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order) and try the suggested solution.
But the problem is while traversing over vertices, I cannot decide which path to choose when there are multiple clockwise options.

Basically, I want to find the following polygonal shapes:

```
* A, E, G, C, D, A
* E, F, G, E 
* E, B, F, E
```

How can I decide to choose G path when I start from A then came to E vertex?

P.S: I am open for a different approach than mine if my approach is not appropriate for this problem or there are better/easier solutions for this

[image: SampleImg]

Comment: `How can I decide to choose G path` I would guess you shouldn't, you can find a polygon with smallest amount of vertices, then cut it (remove non-shared edges, or mark polygon as deleted somehow). Then find next polygon with smallest amount of vertices, etc...

Comment: Yes, finding polygon with the smallest amount of vertices would be another approach. But, then two question needs to be answered:
1. How to find polygon with the smallest amount of vertices?
2. How to solve the overlapping problem? See the [example image](https://imgur.com/8K0bImF). In this case, ABC, ABD, ACD, BCD. all have the smallest number of vertices. How can I decide to discard ABC and keep the rest?

Comment: Ok, while googling 'shortest cycle' I think I've found an answer to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8140/find-all-cycles-faces-in-a-graph

Comment: You'll need a clearer explanation of "all the polygonal shapes of the vertices".  Why would you not select AECD for example?  Or the triangle ACD?  Why will not something like a Delaunay triangulation algorithm suit your purposes?

Comment: @Renat Thanks, the question has a connected question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023310/find-all-cycle-bases-in-a-graph-with-the-vertex-coordinates-given) and I think it is the same with mine. The accepted answer is pretty much same what you suggested. Pseudo code and a working version of the code also provided: https://gist.github.com/mastoj/750015
But, it does not solve the overlapping problem that I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: @Gene Basically, I have a rectangular shape(four vertices and four edges) at the start.  New vertices will be added dynamically and the new vertices will/may divide the rectangular area into smaller pieces. My main purpose is to follow this and calculate each individual area size.

I run into ‘Delaunay triangulation algorithm’ while I was searching for a way to do this. I thought maybe it would be a solution for this but I  couldn’t figure out a way to solve this with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example you are trying to find *faces* of planar graph, defined by its vertices and edges.

**Step 1.** Replace each of your un-directed edges by a pair of directed edges (arcs), connecting vertices in both directions. For each arc (v1 -> v2) find a **next** arc (v2 -> v3), such that both these arcs have the same face **to the left** of them - this can be done by calculating *angles* between arcs and the axis (say) OX and ordering them in clockwise (or counter-clockwise) order. Mark all the arcs as "unused".

**Step 2.** Pick up any "unused" arc and follow next arcs one after another until you reach the origin of the initial arc - you'll get a cycle, bounding a face. You've found a new face with all its arcs/vertices. Mark all the arcs in this cycle as "used". Repeat until there are no "unused" arcs.

Returning to your example - you'll have following arcs:

```
A -> E, E -> A
A -> D, D -> A
B -> E, E -> B
B -> F, F -> B
C -> D, D -> C
C -> G, G -> C
E -> F, F -> E
E -> G, G -> E
F -> G, G -> F
```

Examples of **next** arcs:

- (D -> C) is the next arc for (A -> D)
- (C -> G) is the next arc for (D -> C)
- (G -> E) is the next arc for (C -> G)
- and so on...

This algorithm will find all your internal faces plus one *external* face, bounded by the cycle (A -> E, E -> B, B -> F, F -> G, G -> C, C -> D, D -> A). You can ignore this external face, but in some cases it can be useful - for example, when you're a given a point and you need to find its position relative to your graph as a whole.

Comment: Any idea on how to detect and ignore the external face?

Comment: @Ramriez - consider angles between each arc and its *next* arc. The sum of these angles along the external cycle will be `PI*(n+2)`, and along any internal cycle - `PI*(n-2)`. Here the `n` is length of the cycle.