# Base cycles in undirected graphs

Tags: graph, cycle

I have an undirected graph with coordinates for each edge and vertices between edges, and would like to find the base cycles in this graph.
I am however struggling in finding easy-to-understand algorithms. Could someone indicate me a python-like or c-like script which would help me to achieve this ?
Finding ALL cycles is ok, but my issue is with the base cycles.
Thanks !

Comment: This seems to have been fairly thoroughly answered in [another SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607124/algorithms-to-identify-all-the-cycle-bases-in-a-undirected-graph

Comment: Thanks. I believe an MST is a Minimum Spanning Tree. Let me investigate this direction then !