# Algorithm Problem: Find the longest elementary cycle in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, np

The problem is: given a directed graph, find the longest simple cycle in the graph. I've searched the question and found this link [Finding the longest cycle in a directed graph using DFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530120/finding-the-longest-cycle-in-a-directed-graph-using-dfs). The answer explains this is an NP hard problem.

But I'm confused by the following algorithm, it seems to run in O(|V| + |E|) time because we visit each edge exactly once.

maintain the following variables:

(1) `global max`: the length of the longest cycle in the graph.
(2) `Map<GraphNode, Integer> cache`: stores length of the longest cycle starting from the key node.
(3) `Map<GraphNode, Integer> pathVisited`: stores the node visited on the path and the corresponding step number. For example, A -> B -> C -> A, if starts from A, the Map will look like {A -> 1, B -> 2, C -> 3}, and when enters A again, the step becomes 4, and thus the length of cycle is 4 - 1 = 3
(4)`Set<GraphNode> visited`: contains the graphNodes that have been fully explored.

```
dfs(GraphNode cur, int curStep, Set<GraphNode> visited, Map<GraphNode, Integer> cache, Map<GraphNode, Integer> pathVisited):
    if visited.containsKey(cur), then 
        return // if the node have been explored, no need to explore again
    // if see a cycle, update the results(cache)
    if pathVisited.containsKey(cur), then 
       newCycleLen = curStep - pathVisited.get(cur)
       cache.put(cur, max {newCycleLen, cache.get(cur)})
       return 
    // no cycle yet, continue the search
    pathVisited.put(cur, curStep)
    for each neighbor of cur:
       dfs(neighbor, curStep + 1, cache, pathVisited)
    endfor
    visited.add(cur); // current node have been explored, in the future no need to visit it again.
    path.remove(cur)
```

I feel the above algorithm can solve the problem in O(|V| + |E|) time, because after fully exploring one node, we won't start dfs on that node again.

Can anyone give me some hint on why the above algorithm is wrong?

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: @n.m. yeah some test cases pass, but based on templatetypedef's example the algorithm will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following graph:

```
     D -- A
   / |    |
  E  |    |
   \ |    |
     C -- B
```

Now, imagine you start your DFS at node A and visit the nodes in the order B, then C, then D, and then E. Unless I've misinterpreted what your code is doing, I don't believe that this visitation order will allow you to discover the longest cycle A, B, C, E, D, A, since once you've visited D you've assigned it the wrong depth and cut off the path back to A.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to make sure, the algorithm is wrong in this case because the longest cycle should be of length 5 (A -> B-> C -> E -> D -> A), however, if we visit the graph in the order A->B->D->E, i.e. visit D before E, then via E we will not be able to go back to A because D has been fully explored, so never get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is what is "elementary cycle". DFS is good if cycle have all point visited once time. But This is problem:

```
A---B
|\ /|
| E |
|/ \|
C---D
```

Assume direction:

A -> B

B -> D,E

C -> D

D -> E,A

E -> C

DFS will find longest cycle is 5, A->B->E->C->D->A but longest cycle should be A->B->E->C->D->E->A. Maybe you should try with new view

Comment: ABECDEA is not a simple cycle.