# Detect cycles in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding all cycles in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph)

can anybody give me tutorial,algorithm,... for detect cycles in graph ?

i find several algorithm and implement them but doesn't detect all cycles

[strongly_connected_components_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm)

Comment: I think question there, although mared as "answered" it is not answered correctly.

Comment: @Cygn That is not a reason to allow dups. Just go there and "heat" the question by posting a comment stating that

Comment: There is an implementation to detect all cycles in a graph in the python lib called `networkx`. **It is really simple to use!**
I gave a detailed answer in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph/33956957#33956957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From more mathematical point of view:

Input: Graph G=(V,E)

1. Assume that your graph is not disjoint (there exists a path between every two vertices)
2. Compute the [spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) T of the graph (there are easy algorithms to do that)
3. Let E' be a subset of E, that don't belong to the spanning tree T. For each edge e in E', its addition to the tree creates exactly a single cycle. Let's put all those cycles into set B.
4. We define a [binary cycle space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) over cycles in your graph. In that space, two cycles can be added. The addition is simply an exclusive sum over the edges.
5. The set of cycles B is a "cycle basis". Every other cycle in your graph can be formed as a linear combination of the cycles B.

This way you obtain all possible cycles in your graph.

**Warning:** if your input graph has *v* vertices and *e* edges then there are 2^(*e* - *v* +1)-1 different cycles! That's quite a lot - you might not want to explicitly write all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A BFS alg. is also ok. I believe it's easier to implement than DFS, since it keeps the visited / to-visit nodes in a queue. It's easier to check if a certain nodes has already been visited.

Answer (score -2):

I think DFS will do your job coz we mark visited node and if we find that node again there is a cycle

Comment: This approach is incorrect. Take this example 
`1 -> 2
2 -> 3
1 -> 3`
Now in this case, we do dfs(1). This will inturn will call dfs(2) and mark 2 as visited. This will call dfs(3) and mark 3 as visited.
now dfs(3) will again be called from node 1, and since its already visited, you will incorrectly deduce that its a cycle