# find cycles of specific length

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle

is it possible to find all the cycles of order 5 for example in a graph with 15 vertex. I heard about biconnected componenents but my graph is only one strongly connected components.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all cycles in graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph)

Comment: thanks for the link, my graph is undirected not directed it is still working?

Comment: With a undirected graph, you will get a lot of circles, if you are not more specific (i.e. if you only need real circles and not closed circles, then there are fewer). Also if you also take into account closed walks, the order becomes more or less meaningless. Because of this also any algorithm, which used SCCs does not make sense.

Comment: I need all the closed circles of order 15 in a undirected graph

Answer (score 0):

At the max there are 15P5 = 360,360 options for the cycles, so a simple brute force would be enough