# Loop in a binary tree represented in adjacency list form

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I attained an interview where I was asked a question as below:

> You are given with `parent -----> child` relationships i.e. `N1 --->
>   N2` where `N1` is the parent of `N2`. This is nothing but representing a
>   binary tree in adjacency list form. So I had to find whether there is a loop is present or not.

I have been mulling over this and came up with a solution:

Just need to check individual node i.e. `N1` and  try going deep if you see there is a edge coming back to `N1` then print. Else go for next node. But the interviewer told me that it is not very efficient, can somebody help me in finding an efficient solution. Thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352480/find-a-loop-in-a-binary-tree

Comment: @DarshanPatel this question is different. Just check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in a simple manner:

In a binary tree of N nodes will have N-1 edges. If it has loop then a binary tree having N nodes will have more than N-1 edges.

So you need to calculate the no of nodes and edges (parent->child) if the no_of_nodes == no_of_edges-1 than no loop else has loop.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Do you not also have to check that it's connected?

Comment: @Anonymous could not get you.

Answer (score 0):

Tree is a graph. So you should apply any algorithm for graph traversing, for instance BFS (breadth-first search) or DFS (depth-first search).

Both algorithms use O(V) of memory to store list of vertices (V - # of vertices) and take O(E) time to complete (E - # of edges, between V and V^2). So basically in both algorithms you need to explore all edges once.

The algorithm to identify loops in your tree is as simple as:

1) Take root node

2) Traverse through graph (breadth-first or depth-first) remembering visited nodes

3) If you visit a node that has already been visited, then you have a loop. Increment your loop counter, backtrack and go to 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. check the graph is connected.
2. check that there's exactly E+1 vertices when you're given E edges.

You can apply [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to identify the connected components of the graph. After you've applied it, you can both check that you have exactly one connected component, and that the number of vertices is E+1.