# Generating isochrone maps from road networks

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, graphics, maps

I wonder if there's any described algorithm that can convert isochrones into approximate area to show a range of some feature (in my problem this feature is a road network).

**Example.** I have something like on the image beneath:

[image: road network]

It's a simple network (where I can arrive from the start point in `X` minutes or going `Y` kilometers). I have information of all the nodes and links. Now I need to create an isochrone map that show an approximate range where I can arrive.

Problems:

1. `Convex hull` - sucks because of too general approximation,
2. I can create buffors on roads - so I will get some polygon that shows range, but I will also have the holes by roads that connect into circles.

What I need to obtain is something like this:

[image: isochrone map]

I've found some potentially useful information [HERE](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Isochrone#Creating_isochrones), but there are only some ideas how it could be done. If anyone has any concept, please, help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem (it's not so fast and robust, but has to be enough for now).

1. I generated my possible routes using `A* (A-Star) algorithm`.
2. I used @Artur Gower's idea from point one to eliminate cycles and simplify my geometry.

Later I decided to generate 2 types of gemetries (1st - like on the image, 2nd - simple buffers):

1st one:
3. Then I have removed the rest of unnecessary points using `Douglas-Peucker algorithm` (very fast!).
4. In the end I used `Concave Hull algorithm` (aka `Alpha-Shapes` or `Non-Convex Hull`).

2nd one:
3. Apply a buffer to the existing geometry and take the exterior ring (`JTS` library made that really easier:)).

Comment: How fast is your approach for e.g. a 30min walk time? BTW: A* is not really the correct thing here, just explore the graph via Dijkstra

Comment: Sorry, I changed the company. No more access to that code:/

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem, to get better answers you might want to define exactly what will this area that shows the range (isochrone map) be used for? For example is it illustrative? If you define what kind of approximation you want it could help you solve the problem.

Now here are some ideas.

1) Find all the [cycles in the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph) (see link), then eliminate edges that are shared between two cycles. Finally take the convex hull of the remaining cycles, this together with all the roads, so that the outliers that do not form cycles are included, will give a good approximation for an isochrome map.

2) A simpler solution is to define a thickness around each point of every road, this thickness should be inversely proportional to how long it takes to arrive at that point from the starting point. I.e. the longer it takes to arrive at the point the less thick. You can then scale the thickness of all points until all wholes are filled, and then you will have an approximate isochrome map. One possible way of implementing this is to run an algorithm that takes all possible routes simultaneously from the starting point, branching off at every new intersection, while tracking how long it took to arrive at each point. During its execution, at every instant of time all previously discovered route should be thickened. At the end you can scale this thickness so as to fill all wholes.

Hopefully this will be of some help. Good luck.

Comment: 1. Good idea with extracting edged that are shared between two cycles to avoid too many vertices. But there is a problem with convex hull, because the cases when you have a tree with very long routes will make a convex polygon. We would want something star-like in that case, any ideas how to obtain that?:)