# Graph Set Grouping

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have been trying to solve this problem in the past few days, But I don't know if this algorithm already exist.

So basically, in the image. I should be able to get 3 sets (enclosed ones)

1. A, C, D, B
2. C, D, F, E, G
3. A, C, F, G, E, D, B

[image]

I tried Breadth first but it seems that the "already visited" rule will not handle it,
does anyone has an idea on which tree search I should look into?

The reason for this is for polygon separation.

Comment: If I have understood correctly you are basically trying to count the cycles in a graph. Following link may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph/ Also, isn't ACFGEDB also a group?

Comment: Could you mention explicitly WHY you should get those sets... (just to be sure solutions will really match you requirements)

Comment: *"already visited" rule will not handle it*. Not handle what? That's how you find a cycle, a search re-discovers a vertex.

Comment: @subsub, I will use it to divide a polygon.

Comment: I don't see trees here.

Comment: The problem for an arbitrary graph is NP-hard. It's called #CYCLE or #CYCLES. See e.g. [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f11/lecture23.pdf).