# How to find all cycles containing some vertex in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a directed graph, what the algorithm can find out all cycles that contain a specific vertex *v*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all cycles in graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tarjan's algorithm for strongly connected components will give you the SCC, to which that specific vertex belongs. Now you can run a backtracking algorithm on the SCC to find all the **simple cycles**, which start and end on `v`.