# Cycle through graph back to starting node

Tags: python, graph, nodes, depth-first-search, edges

having an issue working out how to cycle back to the start node in my graph. Currently, from the graph I create I can cycle from a start node and follow the edges till there are no connected nodes. However I can't work out how to make it cycle through and finish on the start node, if possible.

This is an example of the graph with its connections.

```
Node & Connection(S) [(0, 4), (1, 5), (1, 8), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 3), (5, 0), 
(5, 3), (5, 7), (6, 0), (6, 4), (7, 0), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7)]
```

This is my code to cycle through the graph and follow its edges.

```
def pathSearch(graph, start, path=[]):
    path=path+[start]
    for node in graph[start]:
        if not node in path:
            path=pathSearch(graph, node, path)
    return path
print ('Path ', pathSearch(g, 0))
```

This is what I get as an output starting from node 0:

```
pathSearch [0, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6]
```

This is right, but why isn't it doing a full cycle back to the start node?

Comment: See how it should be done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40834276/6499160).