# What is an algorithm to find the circuit with max weight in a directed graph?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, graph-theory, cycle

First problem was that i couldn't find an algorithm that,given an directed graph as input, gives as output a list of all cycles present in the graph. (This problem should be NP-complete).

After thinking about the problem for a while I realized that what probably I really needed was to find the circuit (it can have duplicate vertex but not duplicate edges) with max weight (sum of the weights of the edges).

It should be a NP-complete problem too, and a way to proceed could be to list  all circuits present in the graph and then to sort them by sum of edge weights.

Do you know some algorithm that gives as output a list of all circuits present in a **directed** graph? Or one that find the circuit with max weight ?

I have found this, but it's not exactly what i need.

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0205007

However do you confirm the computational complexity of these problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do sth. like here: [Finding all cycles in a directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph).

You do this search for every node and parallelize that so as to reduce runtime. Afterwards you apply an efficient sort-algorithm to your list of cycle where each cycle is a list of nodes. Sorting algorithms may me Mergesort or Quicksort for instance, but choose which ever u prefer..

I hope that brings u forward.