# Finding all cycles in a Directed Multigraph with self edges

Tags: go, graph, cycle

Is there any implementation of an algorithm finding all the cycles in a directed multigraph with self edges in Golang ? I found out that the [Johnson's algo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-a-directed-graph) is the best solution for directed graphs and an implementation is given in [gonum](https://github.com/gonum/gonum/blob/master/graph/topo/johnson_cycles.go) but it works only on directed graphs (not multigraphs) and it does not support self edges (actually directed graphs in gonum don't support self edges). Is there any short/clever hack that I can do in gonum to make johnson's work for directed multigraphs with self edges ? Or is there any other implementation in Golang ?

One thing that can be done is to create a dummy node between self edges and the duplicate edges between same pair of nodes. This will remove all self edges and graph will be a directed one and I can use the Johnson's here. But is there any better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- self edges : you just have to scan each node of your graph and check if there is a self edge. If there is : add `X -> X` to the list of cycles
- multi graph : the first algorithm will produce paths as a sequence of vertices `X1 -> X2 -> X3 -> ...`. When you have this list, iterate over all the possible edges going from `X1` to `X2`, then all the possible edges going from `X2` to `X3`, etc ...

---

- "clever" hack : from your multigraph `G`, create a new graph `G2`, where the *edges* of `G` also appear as vertices :

```
# if A and B are connected     # create the following 3 vertices and
# by a single edge in G :      # 2 edges in G2 :

   A ---w--> B                     A -> w -> B


# if A and B are connected     # create the following 4 vertices and
# by two edges in G :          # 4 edges in G2 :

     /--x--\                           /-> x --\
    A       B                        A          B
     \--y--/                           \-> y --/

# etc ...
```

then run your cycle enumeration on `G2`, and adapt the output as needed.