# Algorithm to find the number of distinct paths in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graph Algorithm To Find All Connections Between Two Arbitrary Vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices)

I have a directed graph, what algorithm can i use to find the number of distinct acyclic paths between 2 particular vertices, and count the maximum times any path is used in these distinct paths? 
Two paths are distinct if they either visit a different number of vertices or visit vertices in a different order.

Comment: IMHO This need not to be a duplicate. There is a difference between knowing the number of values (integer) and knowing all the values (a set of lists of nodes). For my purpose, even a reasonable guess of the number (upper bound) is OK so for me this is not a duplicate.

Comment: [Graph Algorithm To Find All Connections Between Two Arbitrary Vertices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/58306) is not a duplicate at all: enumerating and counting are different problems, and a directed graph is a different beast from an undirected graph. Regarding the complexity of counting simple paths, see [How hard is counting the number of simple paths between two nodes in a directed graph?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/423) on [cs.se].

Comment: I agree with Danatel - for large graphs, it is undesirable to count an enumeration of all possible paths.

Answer (score 5):

If you follow a slightly modified Dijkstra's algorithm, you can have an all-pair solution.

**Explanation**: Paths from `u` to `v` is the sum of the following:

1. Paths from `u` to `v` which doesn't pass through `w`
2. Paths which go through `w` = number of paths from `u` to `w` **times** number of paths from `w` to `v`

Initialise the matrix with zeros except when there is an edge from `i` to `j` (which is 1).
Then the following algorithm will give you the result (all-pair-path-count)

```
for i = 1 to n:
    for j = 1 to n:
        for k = 1 to n:
            paths[i][i] += paths[i][k] * paths[k][j]
```

Needless to say : **`O(n^3)`**

Eager to read a single pair solution. :)

Comment: This solution doesn't deal correctly with the requirement that the paths must have no cycles.

Comment: This is a modified Bellman-Ford, not a modified Dijkstra (hence the cycle issue).