# adjacency list of a directed weighted graph

Tags: java, collections, adjacency-list

I am using adjacency lists to represent a directed weighted graph and based on the example code provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices/58446#58446) SO question, I have created the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class _Graph {
    private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>>> map = new HashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>>>();

    public void addEdge(String node1, String node2, int dist) {
        LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        HashMap<String, Integer> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        if(adjacent==null) {
            adjacent = new LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>>();                       
            map.put(node1, adjacent);
        }
        innerMap.put(node2, dist);
        adjacent.add(innerMap);
    }

    public boolean isConnected(String node1, String node2) {
        Set<HashMap<String, Integer>> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            return false;
        }
        return adjacent.contains(node2);
    }

    public LinkedList<HashMap<String, Integer>> adjacentNodes(String node) {
        LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>> adjacent = map.get(node);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            return new LinkedList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
        }
        return new LinkedList<HashMap<String, Integer>>(adjacent);
    }

}
```

I am having trouble making the `isConnected` method to work properly. Am I using a wrong data structure to represent the graph here (`Map<String, LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String, Integer>>>`)? The hashmap will hold the name of the connected node and the distance to it:

```
Map<startNode, LinkedHashSet<HashMap<endNode, distanceToEndNode>>>
```

1. Basically how can I check if a node
   belongs to the adjacency list of a
   given base node? I think the problem
   is reduced to iterating properly
   over the `adjacent`
   `Set<HashMap<String, Integer>>`
   structure, or is my reasoning wrong?
2. In my second method
   `adjacentNodes(String node)` I am
   returning a linked list containing
   the maps (in a set structure) of the
   connected nodes and their distances. How could I efficiently iterate to see all connections of a any given node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `LinkedHashSet` is not needed here, you can represent the graph with just a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

`isConnected` is basically what you already have:

```
public boolean isConnected(String node1, String node2) {
    Map<String, Integer> adjacent = map.get(node1);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return adjacent.containsKey(node2);
}
```

`adjacentNodes` just needs to pull out the entries in the hash set for the source node

```
public Collection<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> adjacentNodes(String node) {
    Map<String, Integer> adjacent = map.get(node);
    if(adjacent==null) {
        return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>();
    }
    return adjacent.entrySet();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, should I change adjacent.contains(node2);  to adjacent.containsKey(node2);

Comment: The initialization of the Map in both these function gives an error : "Type mismatch : Cannot convert from LinkedHashSet<HashMap<String,Integer>> to Map<String,Integer>"

Comment: @user782400: I'm saying you don't want to use `LinkedHashSet`.  `map` should have type `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`.  During construction, you probably want to use `HashMap` for your `Map`s.