# Find path from Point A to B with n number of Loops

Tags: php, algorithm, graph, logic

I have a problem that I need guidance with. I have an array that has information about the edges between different nodes. So,

`a[1][39] = 'p'`  --> Take transition 'p' while in node 1 to get to node 39. The complete graph is this:

```
i[1][51] = 'p' 
i[1][39] = 't' 
i[39][40] = 'd' 
i[40][66] = 'p' 
i[66][51] = 'd' 
i[40][41] = 'm' 
i[41][64] = 'd' 
i[64][40] = 'd'
```

As you can see, it's a directed, cyclic graph. **What I need to do** is to have all paths from point X to Y. So, given X=1 and Y=51. I need output like so:

```
o[0][0] = 'p'

o[1][0] = 't'
o[1][1] = 'd'
o[1][2] = 'p'
o[1][3] = 'd'

o[2][0] = 't'
o[2][1] = 'd'
o[2][2] = 'm'
o[2][3] = 'd'
o[2][4] = 'd'
o[2][5] = 'p'
o[2][6] = 'd'
```

The first index shows the path number. So, I have three paths here. The second index shows the step. So, one step in the first path, four in the second.

I'm doing this in PHP but even pseudo-code code would do. Also, I can also reverse the input array to `i[1]['p'] = 51` etc. if that might help.

Thanks.

Comment: Needless to say, this is a subset of the actual, much larger, graph. Also, I can live with cycles for now but will have to cap the loops to a specific number -- say, discard a path if it visits a node more than twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star
2. [Graph Algorithm To Find All Connections Between Two Arbitrary Vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices)

Comment: How is that supposed to help?

Comment: @eisberg I didn't ask the question. How is a heuristic algorithm which returns a single (best) path will help in returning all possible paths? What we need here is not a best answer but an enumeration of paths.

Comment: @rabbitisle So you only need to change the terminating in A-Star and give your self an array of all solutions.

Comment: @rabbitisle I am sorry I cannot rewrite the pseudo code at the moment. But you should be very careful when you collect all possible paths for lets say 20 points you can end up with million possibilities and looping for hours.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Q: If A* finds the shortest path, it wouldn't go through cycles, would it? I need paths with 'n' number of cycles.

Comment: @recluze A-Star is working with lists/stacks and can (without changes) only find one path without cycles. Maybe you can modify http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm for that.

Comment: Again, isn't Dijkstra only able to do shortest paths? I need all paths ... whether they're short or long. I'm not really concerned with distance here. Performance isn't really an issue either.

Comment: @recluze Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices ?

Comment: That looks like a very comprehensive discussion. Thanks.