# How to apply aggregate functions(like MIN, MAX, COUNT) in JCR-SQL2?

Tags: java, aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have some records stored as Nodes in JCR and the name of the node is the primary key. eg 1,2,3.
But the problem starts here,

the records are as follows **1,2,6,53,54**

Where the numbers above are nodes under EMP unstructured node.
If I do

`int count=empNode.getNodeIterator().getSize()` **I will get 5** As there are 5 nodes

So I do count++ which gives me 6 but 6 already exists, **so I can't create a node with name 6 under EMP[nt:unstructred], thats why I want to apply MAX(nodeNames)** something in the query. What should I do ?

**Update ::**
I use CQ5.5. EMP is an unstructered node under content like /content/EMP.
Under this(EMP) I have unstructered nodes that hold my data. And these node have names as 1,2, etc

Comment: Which version of CQ5 do you use? And what is 'EMP'?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackrabbit searches across joined nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871554/jackrabbit-searches-across-joined-nodes)

Answer (score 4):

I tried with my CQ5.4 instance to find a soloution. Unfortunatly my tries were not successful. When I used the keywords 'sql2 count' with Google, I found [this](http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/count-function-in-query-td2294092.html) page. There was asked the same question and the answer was

> There is no count(*) or group by selector in JCR SQL [1](http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/count-function-in-query-td2294092.html), XPath [2] or
> JCR-SQL2/AQM [3].
>
> To implement such a tag cloud, you can run one query that fetches all
> your content containing the relevant "tag" property:
>
> //element(*, my:Article)[@tag]
>
> and then iterate over the result and count your tags on the
> application side by looking at the tag property values and using some
> hashmap (tagid -> count).
>
> http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/ (section 8.5)
>
> http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/1.0/ (section 6.6)
>
> http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html

I think you can connect this answer to MAX() and MIN().

Comment: ::  does that mean that. We fetch all the records we want and then re iterate over it in JCR_SQL2? Or do I have to really do that manually in Java? Or are you talking about writing a procedure in CQ5? The last question is bizzare but just curious!

Comment: Yes, you have to it manually. Fortunatly the `java.util.List` contains the method `size()`.

Comment: :: I understand. but if you see my question properly you'll understand that `list.size()` doesn't help me. I however managed to solve it by maintaining a CounterTable (node) that keeps  a track of the latest used integer instead of doing  list.size() +1 to get the latest int and use it as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple Apache Sling servlet to implement the count(*) function. More information here: https://github.com/artika4biz/sling-utils.
Official documentation can be found here: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/query-engine.html