# D3 js Force Directed Graph - highlight path between two points

Tags: javascript, d3.js, directed-graph

I am using the following force directed example for one of my project.

[Example Link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022)

Here, I need something like: - Highlight the paths between "Microsoft" and "Sony".

Is it possible ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a mouseover listener to the lines in the force layout and add a custom css class providing highlighting as follows:

```
link.on('mouseover', function(d, i){
   d3.select(this).classed('mouseover', true);
})
.on('mouseout', function(d, i){
    d3.select(this).classed('mouseover', false);
});
```

mouseover is a css class with required properties for highlighting.
Highlight happens when you mouse over a particular line.

You can refer to fiddle here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/prashant_11235/Ukb28/

Comment: Thanks Prashant, here I am looking for some algorithm which will give all the paths between the two given nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices) seems to have an algorithm that does what you want, although it's coded in Java. I don't know if that will help.