# How to create path if I have total number of nodes and distance between them?

Tags: java

I want to generate a graph. I have total 3 inputs. total no of nodes and distance between them.

For example,

```
Total no of nodes J = 6, 
no of path can be created from them R = 8
input3 = {1#2#8, 1#4#7, 1#5#12, 2#3#4, 2#4#2, 3#6#6, 4#6#8, 5#6#10}.
```

This information I have. First digit represents the starting node, second digit represents the ending node and third digit represents distance between them i.e. distance between 1st and 2nd node is 8, distance between 1st and 4th node is 7 like that.

Now I want to create paths from them. I need output like this:

```
first path can be 1->2->3-> 6 and total cost for that is 18
second path can be 1->2->4->6 and total cost for that is 18
third path can be 1->4->6 and total cost for that is 15
fourth path can be 1->5->6 and total cost for that is 22
```

How can I implement this type of program in Java?

Comment: I estimate that a full implementation to your problem in Java would be on the order of 100 lines of code or more.  Can you narrow down your question so that it is not so broad?

Comment: but i need to create path from given data only....just forgot about the path values...ok with that...

Comment: Use any search algorithm. For instance BFS.

Comment: @UmNyobe The problem is complicated by the fact that he doesn't necessarily have a root node which can reach all paths in the graph.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen one can consider root node as first value from the array. We have array like this : {1#2#8, 1#4#7, 1#5#12, 2#3#4, 2#4#2, 3#6#6, 4#6#8, 5#6#10}
so you can cosider root node as 1

Comment: This makes the problem substantially simpler.

Comment: you can consider min value as starting node and max value from array as last node..