# Check if Object A can access Object D

Tags: php, function, class, object

I have a code that creates an Object. Let's say we can create an Object A and this object has R1 or R2 directions or permissions to the next Object let's name it Object B, so in order to have access from Object A to object B R1 or R2 has to be 1(or TRUE)

How to implement a function that will check if Object A can access Object D. 
Where in order for Object A it needs to have at least R1 or R2 access to Object Band where Object B needs to have R1 or R2 access to Object C where Object D needs to have at least R1 or R2 access to Object D.

```
<?php

class MyObject {
    function directionsRn($R1, $R2, $objSource, $objDest) {
        if ($R1 == 1) {
            echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R1 <br>");
        } else if ($R1 == 0) {
            echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R1 <br>");
        }  

        if ($R2 == 1) {
            echo("$objSource can access $objDest via R2<br>");
        }  else if ($R2 == 0) {
            echo("SORRY, but $objSource CANNOT access $objDest via R2 <br>");
        }
    }
}

$myObject_array[0] = new MyObject();
$myObject_array[1] = new MyObject();
$myObject_array[2] = new MyObject();

$myObject_array[0]->directionsRn(0, 1, 'A', 'B');
$myObject_array[1]->directionsRn(1, 0, 'D', 'B');
$myObject_array[2]->directionsRn(1, 0, 'C', 'D');

print_r($myObject_array);
```

Comment: This question is a little unclear - are "R"s a route or something? What is the expected output of your example code?

Comment: "R"s are the names of access directions it can be anything it's just a name for an access direction. In this case there may be only two access directions for example A to B A has R1 and R2 access directions (literally arrows from A to B) where 0(zero) means no access via R1 for example and if R2 == 1 it means A has access to B via R2

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) where your objects are nodes (A,B, etc) and the permissions between the objects are edges.

Connection between any two nodes can be resolved with [bread first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), in which you try to access to new nodes from the set of nodes you have already access by a distance of one edge. Important point is to ignore already accessed elements by flagging them as already-seen (with an array of boolean)

You can also find different approaches for checking connection of two nodes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306/graph-algorithm-to-find-all-connections-between-two-arbitrary-vertices)

Comment: this is not quiet exactly what i am looking for the graph represented in those articles have one direction in my case it can be from A to B and from D to B then from D to C and from C to D and that's it. How to check and confirm that A is not having access to C ?

Comment: As a general approach to apply one directional graph solutions on bidirectionals, you just process that if an edge from A to B, there's also an edge from B to A.

Comment: no, that's why i called them directions let's say A can have R1 and R2 both directed to B but Object B only has one direction to Object D